# Consumer not reading provider value

Tags: reactjs, react-context

This is my Provider component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent/MyComponent';

     export default function App(props) {
    const [header, setHeader] = useState(null);

    function setHeaderText(header) {
        setHeader(header);
    }

    const contextItems = {
        setHeaderText: setHeaderText,
        what: 'what'
    };

    return <React.Fragment>
        <AppContext.Provider value={contextItems}>
            <MyComponent request={props.request}/>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>

}

export const AppContext = React.createContext({
    setHeaderText: () => {},
    what: ''
});
```

I am using the consumer to try and pass the context value to MyComponent which is a functional component.

```
function MyComponent() {...}

export default (props) => {
    return <AppContext.Consumer>
        { value => <MyComponent context={value} {...props} />}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
}
```

My issue is that it only passes the default value of AppContext not the value that i am passing in.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code at all?

I am using the latest version of react 16.8.2.

Thanks for any help.

Side note: I know i could just use composition in this case but the header value will be used throughout the app.

Comment: [Your code seems to work fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxo3m940lr).

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong with my instance then. Thank you for checking it.

Comment: Have you updated your `react-dom` to `16.8.2` as well?

Comment: Yeah its a fresh project, they are both 16.8.2

Comment: `My issue is that it only passes the default value of AppContext not the value that i am passing in.` . By default value do you mean `{
    setHeaderText: () => {},
    what: ''
}` or `{
        setHeaderText: setHeaderText,
        what: 'what'
    };`

Comment: I mean that what i am revieiving is { setHeaderText: () => {}, what: '' } when i have set the value as { setHeaderText: setHeaderText, what: 'what' }. If the default value is null i also receive null